# Defining an Alias to Image Magick in Fish Shell

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, alias, fish

I would like to use Image Magick to trim some images via

```
convert -trim image.png image.png
```

Is there a way to register an alias in Fish Shell, that would shorten the above statement to something like this?

```
trim image.png
```

If so, how do I implement this?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the fish documentation for functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fish` does not have aliases; you need to define a function instead.

```
function trim
    convert -trim $argv[1] $argv[1]
end
```

Running `fish -c help` (or simply `help` if you are already in a `fish` session)
 will open the `fish` documentation in a web browser, where you can find the documentation for the `function` command used to define shell functions.